# Download file(Image) using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write code to download image in WordPress, the image download correctly but image not opening after download , I have tried same code without WordPress its wok correctly , I want it to run in WordPress also

### My code

```
<form method="post">     
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
function sendHeaders($file, $type, $name=NULL)
{
    if (empty($name))
    {
        $name = basename($file);
    }
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'";');
    header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $file = 'logo.png';
    if (is_file($file))
    {
        sendHeaders($file, 'image/png', 'My picture.png');
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        @readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

---

image after download:
[image: logo.png]

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to rename.

- Using Shortcode:

  `[wpfid new_name="new-name-of-file"]`
  You can use variables also like this:
  `[wpfid new_name="%post_id%"]`,
  `[wpfid new_name="%filename%_%rand%"]`, etc.
- Bulk Rename Images:

  Goto settings >> Wp-Force Images Download page and set your desired combination to rename images, e.g. `%filename%-%rand%`.

Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-force-images-download/